# My menu connected to my view controller IBAction is greyed

Tags: macos, interface-builder, menuitem, ibaction, xcode-storyboard

I'm building an application using *Xcode Interface Builder* storyboard.

My *VideoViewController* implements the following action:

```
@IBAction func openVideo(sender: AnyObject) {
    ...
}
```

When connecting my menu item to the *First responder*, I can see my action:

[image: connection]

Unfortunately, when I launch my application, the menu item is greyed:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Have you also connected OpenVideo to your ViewController (eg. New Referencing Outlet > ViewController)?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: You should just be able to Control-Click on the Open Video menu item and drag the connector to your VideoViewController. When you do that you should see the openVideo IBAction to connect it to.

Comment: Also, if you don't have an IBOutlet setup, you'll probably need one: (eg.`@IBOutlet var openVideoMenuItem: NSMenuItem!`). That is the bridge between the IBAction and the NSMenuItem.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to control-click the `NSMenuItem` and connect it to your VideoViewController. Usually an `IBOutlet` would be used in order to connect your `IBAction`:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var myMenuItem: NSMenuItem!

    @IBAction func openItem(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("success!")
    }
}
```

[image]

In your particular case you would control-click and drag the connector to your VideoViewController.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm using Storyboard not XIB file

Comment: @MartinDelille: It's the same process regardless of whether the project uses `xibs`, `nibs`, and/or `storyboards`. As mentioned (twice), your code needs an `IBOutlet`, which you've apparently failed to include. The `IBAction` function isn't going to connect to your `NSMenuItem` automatically — the image in my answer should illustrate how to do that. Were you able to try what I've suggested?

Comment: other question: what tool did you use to generate this awesomely clear GIF animation? :-)

Comment: @MartinDelille: I used screenflow to create a lossless screencast, then used gifbrewery to import the video and generate the animated gif. It might sound complicated but literally took two minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Regarding my problem, I understand that I have to connect my `NSMenuItem IBOutlet` but I don't understand from what since I dont have *Objects/Delegate* in my scene.

Comment: You would connect the `NSMenuItem` to your `VideoViewController` (rather than Object/Delegate from the example), which is where I presume your `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` are located. When you drag the connection to the controller from the menu item and vice versa the available outlets should appear.

Comment: When dragging from my `NSMenuItem` to my `VideoViewController` I have a *Action Segue* popup with *Show, Custom* and *Modal* for a choice. When dragging my `VideoViewController` to my `NSMenuItem`, I have no connection available.

Comment: Would it help to see an example project perhaps? It's odd that you have a greyed out `NSMenuItem` in the first place (maybe it's not selected as "enabled"?). When I add a new one it's not greyed out by default even if it's not connected to anything. Something you might try as a test is to create a new project put an `IBAction` and `IBOutlet` in AppDelegate.swift and see if you can connect the `NSMenuItem`.

Comment: I managed to make it work with a simpler example. I might have problem with my NSSplitterController...

Answer (score 1):

I know OP found a solution, and even though I downloaded his project, I couldn't enable (un-gray out) my menu item.

Here's what worked for me:

- Create an `@IBAction` in the target `ViewController`
- Override `func validateMenuItem(_ menuItem: NSMenuItem) -> Bool` in the target `ViewController` (it must return `true` when it validates that `menuItem` is indeed the `menuItem` you are willing to connect to your `@IBAction`)
- Connect `MenuItem` to `First Responder` and then to the `@IBAction` you created earlier

That's it. Hit run and exhale.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are missing an underscore for the parameter. If you add that it will work with First Responder. Additionally for Swift 3 onwards, the sender type should be `Any`, or the specific control type such as `NSMenuItem`, although it will still work with `AnyObject`.

```
@IBAction func openVideo(_ sender: Any) {
    ...
}
```